# Как в Сказке о царе Салтане А. С. Пушкина появился «крещёный мир»?

Tags: литература, пушкин

Современный текст сказки выглядит так:

> Три девицы под окном
>  Пряли поздно вечерком.
>  «Кабы я была
> царица, —
>  Говорит одна девица, —
>  То на весь **крещеный
> мир**
>  Приготовила б я пир»…
> *[[wikisource.org](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_(%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD)), Источник: Пушкин, А. С. Сказка о царе Салтане, о сыне его славном и могучем богатыре князе Гвидоне Салтановиче и о прекрасной царевне Лебеди // Полное собрание сочинений: в 10 т. — Л. : Наука. Ленингр. отд-ние, 1977—1979. — Т. 4. Поэмы. Сказки. — 1977. — С. 313—337.]*

Однако в издании 1832 года текст выглядит так:

> Три дѣвицы подъ окномъ
>  Пряли поздно вечеркомъ.
>  Кабы я была
> царица,
>  Говорить одна дѣвица,
>  То **сама** на весь **бы**
> міръ
>  Приготовила я пиръ…
> *[[pushkinskijdom.ru](http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/Default.aspx?tabid=9720), Сказка о Царе Салтане, о сыне его, славном и могучем богатыре Князе Гвидоне Салтановиче и о прекрасной Царевне Лебеди («Три девицы под окном») — Стихотворения Александра Пушкина. Третья часть. Санктпетербург. Печатано в типографии Департамента народного просвещения. 1832. Стр. 130-181.]*

Автор [penrosa](https://users.ucrazy.ru/penrosa/) в статье «[Пушкин уже не тот](https://ucrazy.ru/other/1449649148-pushkin-uzhe-ne-tot.html)» на сайте [ucrazy.ru](https://ucrazy.ru/) приводит издания 1948, 1946, 1936 и 1889, где нет «крещёного мира».

В [примечаниях, составленных Л. С. Сидяковым](http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/texts/selected/sid/sid-458-.htm?cmd=0&hash=%25D2%25D0%25C5%25D2%25DC%25DF.1831.IV) в книге *Пушкин А. С. Стихотворения / Рос. АН. — СПб.: Наука, 1997* сказано:

> В текст СП₃ введены некоторые изменения, вероятно, цензурного
> характера: в основном тексте сказки, печатаемом в современных
> изданиях, восстановлены чтения писарской копии с поправками автора и
> П. А. Плетнева в цензурной рукописи СП₃. Ст. 5—6:
>
> То на весь крещеный мир
> Приготовила б я пир…

Получается, что «крещёный мир» появился после того, как кто-то решил восстановить текст автора в состояние до цензурных правок.

Но в примечаниях Сидякова сказано «…введены некоторые изменения, вероятно, цензурного
характера…», т. е. вообще не понятно: это цензор убрал «крещёный мир» или сам Пушкин. Почему цензору мог бы не понравиться «крещёный мир»? И был ли он автографе Пушкина вообще?

В черновом автографе Пушкина 1928 года нет «крещёного мира»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник изображения: [a-s-pushkin.ru](http://a-s-pushkin.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000028/st049.shtml), ['Сказка о царе Салтане'. Черновой автограф. 1828](http://a-s-pushkin.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000028/pic/000014.jpg)

---

- Как всё-таки появился «крещёный мир» в тексте сказки?
- Принадлежит ли такой вариант текста авторству Пушкина?
- Если это восстановленный текст в состояние до цензурных правок, то где первоисточник, по которому восстанавливали? Что плохого цензор мог видеть в «крещёном мире»? Или, может, это просто был какой-то промежуточный вариант, который сам Пушкин отверг впоследствии? Ведь написано: «…изменения, вероятно, цензурного характера…», значит, не известно, было ли это требованием цензора. Был ли «крещёный мир» в автографе Пушкина вообще?
- Насколько современные издатели вправе менять текст и делать его не соответствующим тексту прижизненного издания поэта?

Comment: @Артём Луговой Спасибо за правки.

Comment: Не за что, Eagle!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, «крещёный мир» в «Сказке о царе Сатане» появился именно из рукописи Пушкина — более поздней, чем ваша, наверное, уже беловой. Откуда вы взяли, что «Сказка...» основана на языческой мифологии? Царь Салтан и князь Гвидон с жёнами *венчаются*, — это церковный обряд; в городе, возникшем на острове, «блещут маковки церквей и святых монастырей»; далее в нём же «хор церковный Бога хвалит»; корабельщики, рассказывая царю Салтану об удивительном городе, специально отмечают, что он — христианский: «с златоглавыми церквами»; Гвидона и царевну-лебедь мать Гвидона благословляет «иконой чудотворной». А в издании 1832 «крещёный мир», скорее всего, пропал именно из-за цензурной правки, — да, скорее всего, именно царский цензор зарезал слово «крещёный»! Поскольку, видимо, решил, что вне разговора непосредственно о церковных реалиях это — упоминание священного понятия всуе. Вот что пишет Ю. М. Лотман в «Комментарии к роману А С Пушкина "Евгений Онегин"»:

> Прежде всего следует отметить, что гадание «на сон» представляет собой обычное для
> святочных гаданий опасное действие, в ходе которого гадающий вступает в общение с
> нечистой силой. Приступая к такому гаданию, девушки снимают с себя кресты, пояса (пояс — древний языческий символ защитительного круга — сохраняет значение оберега и в русских этнографических материалах). Формула информантов, описывающих святочное гадание: «Сняли с себя кресты, немытика помянули» (Максимов, цит. соч., с. 6) — указывает на призывание черта. П., видимо, был осведомлен в этой («черной») стороне святочных гаданий. Не случайно он подчеркнул, что Татьяна «поясок шелковый Сняла» (V, X, 9-10) — **упомянуть о снимании креста, конечно, не было возможности. Вспомним, что выражение «на этом глупом небосклоне» (III, V, 12) печатно было объявлено кощунственным («Едва смеешь верить глазам своим!» — восклицал критик альманаха «Северная звезда» на 1829 г. М. А. Бестужев-Рюмин), ср. также цензурные трудности с публикацией баллады Жуковского «Иванов вечер»**. См.: Сухомлинов М. И. Исследования и статьи по русской литературе и просвещению, т. I. СПб., 1889, с. 444–447.
>
> https://www.informaxinc.ru/lib/pushkin/lotman_eo1.html

Вот похожая история с «Детством» Л. Н. Толстого:

> О цензурных вымарках и заменах в «Детстве» (не зная их происхождения и с горечью и досадой относя на счет редактора) Толстой писал Н. А. Некрасову[1]. На первой же странице повести в «Современнике» «образок моего ангела» (т. е. иконка), висевший над кроватью мальчика, был заменен «портретом моей маменьки».
>
> http://feb-web.ru/feb/tolstoy/texts/selectpr/dou/dou-509-.htm?cmd=p